# Get VB.net Enum Description from Value

Tags: vb.net, enums

How can I get `Enum` description from its value?

I can get the description from the name using:

```
Public Shared Function GetEnumDescription(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
    Dim fi As FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
    Dim attr() As DescriptionAttribute = _ 
                  DirectCast(fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), _
                  False), DescriptionAttribute())

    If attr.Length > 0 Then
        Return attr(0).Description
    Else
        Return EnumConstant.ToString()
    End If
End Function
```

But I cant figure out how to pass a variable name to this function. I've tried things like

```
GetEnumDescription([Enum].GetName(GetType(myEnum), 2)))
```

but nothing I've tried is correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have a variable of your enum type, it's simply

```
GetEnumDescription(myEnum)
```

Minimal working example:

```
Enum TestEnum
    <Description("Description of Value1")>
    Value1
End Enum

Public Sub Main()
    Dim myEnum As TestEnum = TestEnum.Value1
    Console.WriteLine(GetEnumDescription(myEnum)) ' prints "Description of Value1"
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

---

If you have an `Integer` variable, you need to cast it to your enum type first (`CType` works as well):

```
GetEnumDescription(DirectCast(myEnumValue, TestEnum))
```

Working example:

```
Enum TestEnum
    <Description("Description of Value1")>
    Value1 = 1
End Enum

Public Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(GetEnumDescription(DirectCast(1, TestEnum)))
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

The source for your confusion seems to be a misunderstanding: Your method does not take the "name" of an enum as a parameter, it takes an `Enum` as a parameter. That's something different, and it's also the reason why your attempts to use `GetName` failed.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work... it only works with MyEnum.name but I don't have the name, only the value.

Comment: @doovers: Updated my answer. You simply need a cast.

Comment: thanks man I knew it would be simple but I couldn't figure it out!

Comment: GetEnumDescription doesn't exist for me. I had to add it using an extension as shown in the answer provided by @mikro

Comment: @tmighty: It's not a built-in, it's a method written by the OP and can be found in the question itself.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another solution to get an Enum's description as an extension.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

<Extension()> Public Function GetEnumDescription(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
    Dim attr() As DescriptionAttribute = DirectCast(EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())
    Return If(attr.Length > 0, attr(0).Description, EnumConstant.ToString)
End Function
```

Example use from the previous posts:

```
Enum Example
    <Description("Value1 description.")> Value1 = 1
    <Description("Value2 description.")> Value2 = 2
End Enum

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(DirectCast(2, Example).GetEnumDescription())
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```