# Enum with option to show up second describtion

Tags: vb.net

I have some enum inside my code (below) and i am using this enum to show up the names like e.g that: Datasource.Some_server1.ToString(). I am using it either inside code engine to do some calculation if specific server enum is and also to show the name on the webpage. The problem now is my manager asked me to show up diffrent names. So for instance not Some_server1 but for instance: HHGT Server 56. The problem is my code is using those enum names to do some tasks and i cannot just change it within this enum. Do you know some way i can tell inside my project ok now i want see describtion name for this enum so not Some_server1 but now if Datasource.Some_server1.ToString() then show HHGT Server 56. Is there such possibility without not changing my enum in the way rest of code is still using it? Hope you got what i mean.

```
Public Enum Datasource
    Some_server1
    Some_server2
    Some_server3
    Some_server4
End Enum
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888519/get-vb-net-enum-description-from-value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more context to your Enum by assigning a [Description Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to each member.

```
Public Enum DataSource
    <Description("HHGT Server 56")> Some_server1
    'etcetera
End Enum
```

Then you can use this function (taken from [a really useful extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6294/Description-Enum-TypeConverter)) to get the Description string:

```
Public Shared Function GetEnumDescription(ByVal value As [Enum]) As String
    Dim fi As Reflection.FieldInfo = value.[GetType]().GetField(value.ToString())
    Dim attributes As DescriptionAttribute() = DirectCast(fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())
    Return If((attributes.Length > 0), attributes(0).Description, value.ToString())
End Function
```

Comment: Also see [dbasnett's link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999302/enum-with-option-to-show-up-second-describtion/31000018#comment50027712_30999302) for a very similar example. ...Someone always seems quicker on the draw than I am.