# System.MissingMemberException: The public member description for the type was not found

Tags: vb.net, enums

I have the following code in VB.NET since some years, and it worked fine:

```
Public Enum eAussendienstlerVermittler
    <Description("Undefined")> Undefined = 0
    <Description("Jack")> Jack = 1
    <Description("John")> John = 2
    <Description("Tom")> Tom = 3
    <Description("Martha")> Martha = 4
End Enum


    For Each e In System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(eAussendienstlerVermittler))

        Dim nItem As iGDropDownListItem
        nItem = New iGDropDownListItem

        nItem.Value = CInt(CType(e, Integer))
        nItem.Text = e.Description 'Raises error 

        _DropDownListAußendienstler.Items.Add(nItem)

    Next
```

Now I did something that I am not aware of, and I get the error

"System.MissingMemberException: The public member description for the type eAussendienstlerVermittler was not found."

in the first

```
nItem.Text = e.Description
```

What may I have done to cause this error?

Thank you!

Comment: See also [Get VB.net Enum Description from Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18888519/880990).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CType(e, Integer) already is an Integer, so there is no need to convert it a second time.

it is a misconception of enum types as the name of each elements isn't description but the name it self for example

[image]

So when you loopß over all values, you get the name like jack as node, which you can access by converting ot to string

So your code would look like

```
For Each e As eAussendienstlerVermittler In System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(eAussendienstlerVermittler))

    Dim nItem As iGDropDownListItem
    nItem = New iGDropDownListItem

    nItem.Value = CType(e, Integer)
    nItem.Text = e.ToString

    _DropDownListAußendienstler.Items.Add(nItem)

Next
```

Comment: I have no idea why I did it like I did in the first place. I'm sure the question will come up again. Until then thank you very much!